# Unable to boot Ubuntu on Acer Aspire ES17

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi, acer, bios

After initially trying to install dual booting Ubuntu+Windows 10 and now having removed Windows 10 (made back-up with Macrium reflect), I'm trying to install Ubuntu (unsuccessful for many days).

I have tried the following steps:

- [Booting Ubuntu on Acer Aspire ES 17](https://askubuntu.com/questions/824045/booting-ubuntu-on-acer-aspire-es-17)
- https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2297947&p=13369742#post13369742
- [Acer Aspire E15 will not dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/627416/acer-aspire-e15-will-not-dual-boot)
- https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/EFI_Problembehebung/
  (in German)

This Acer laptop has UEFI, no Legacy. In the bios options I have tried both with secure boot enable and disabled.

There is no option to 'Select an UEFI file as trusted for executing'. Booting in live mode (from USB stick) goes fine.

Can anyone give me a hand? Thank you in advance!!

Below is my boot info summary.

I tried overwriting MBR and GPT with zeroes using 'dd', and now boot repair is not working. It doesn't have an option for '(recommended) repair' anymore!

[image: boot repair not displaying options for 'advanced' or 'repair']

Boot Info Script cfd9efe + Boot-Repair extra info      [Boot-Info 26Apr2016]

```
============================= Boot Info Summary: ===============================

 => Syslinux MBR (5.00 and higher) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.
 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdb.

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  SYSLINUX 6.03
    Boot sector info:  Syslinux looks at sector 32792 of /dev/sda1 for its 
                       second stage. The integrity check of Syslinux failed. 
                       No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /syslinux.cfg /casper/vmlinuz.efi 
                       /EFI/BOOT/grubx64.efi /ldlinux.sys

============================ Drive/Partition Info: =============================

Drive: sda _____________________________________________________________________
Disk /dev/sda: 7.6 GiB, 8103395328 bytes, 15826944 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sda1    *          2,048    15,826,943    15,824,896   c W95 FAT32 (LBA)


Drive: sdb _____________________________________________________________________
Disk /dev/sdb: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sdb1                   1 1,953,525,167 1,953,525,167  ee GPT


GUID Partition Table detected.

Partition  Attrs   Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors System

Attributes: R=Required, N=No Block IO, B=Legacy BIOS Bootable, +=More bits set

"blkid" output: ________________________________________________________________

Device           UUID                                   TYPE       LABEL

/dev/loop0                                              squashfs   
/dev/sda1        F083-24B4                              vfat       UBUNTU 16_0
/dev/sdb5        4494e0b5-38c4-4e44-9f26-e376dcd85f76   swap       

========================= "ls -l /dev/disk/by-id" output: ======================

total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Mar 19 10:04 ata-Slimtype_DVD_A_DA8AESH_0080F01164217A3CF101 -> ../../sr0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Mar 19 10:26 ata-TOSHIBA_MQ01ABD100_96JRC6MET -> ../../sdb
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Mar 19 10:26 ata-TOSHIBA_MQ01ABD100_96JRC6MET-part5 -> ../../sdb5
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Mar 19 10:26 usb-USB_Flash_DISK_1403032780018582-0:0 -> ../../sda
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Mar 19 10:26 usb-USB_Flash_DISK_1403032780018582-0:0-part1 -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Mar 19 10:26 wwn-0x5000039744007a3d -> ../../sdb
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Mar 19 10:26 wwn-0x5000039744007a3d-part5 -> ../../sdb5

================================ Mount points: =================================

Device           Mount_Point              Type       Options

/dev/loop0       /rofs                    squashfs   (ro,noatime)
/dev/sda1        /cdrom                   vfat       (ro,noatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)


=========================== sda1/boot/grub/grub.cfg: ===========================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

if loadfont /boot/grub/font.pf2 ; then
    set gfxmode=auto
    insmod efi_gop
    insmod efi_uga
    insmod gfxterm
    terminal_output gfxterm
fi

set menu_color_normal=white/black
set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray

menuentry "Try Ubuntu without installing" {
    set gfxpayload=keep
    linux   /casper/vmlinuz.efi  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper quiet splash ---
    initrd  /casper/initrd.lz
}
menuentry "Install Ubuntu" {
    set gfxpayload=keep
    linux   /casper/vmlinuz.efi  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper only-ubiquity quiet splash ---
    initrd  /casper/initrd.lz
}
menuentry "OEM install (for manufacturers)" {
    set gfxpayload=keep
    linux   /casper/vmlinuz.efi  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper only-ubiquity quiet splash oem-config/enable=true ---
    initrd  /casper/initrd.lz
}
menuentry "Check disc for defects" {
    set gfxpayload=keep
    linux   /casper/vmlinuz.efi  boot=casper integrity-check quiet splash ---
    initrd  /casper/initrd.lz
}
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

============================== sda1/syslinux.cfg: ==============================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DEFAULT loadconfig

LABEL loadconfig
  CONFIG /isolinux/isolinux.cfg
  APPEND /isolinux/
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

=================== sda1: Location of files loaded by Grub: ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)

            ?? = ??             boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1

================= sda1: Location of files loaded by Syslinux: ==================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)

            ?? = ??             syslinux.cfg                                   1
            ?? = ??             ldlinux.sys                                    1

=============================== StdErr Messages: ===============================

File descriptor 9 (/proc/24466/mounts) leaked on lvs invocation. Parent PID 29714: bash
File descriptor 63 (pipe:[67193]) leaked on lvs invocation. Parent PID 29714: bash

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION :
=================== log of boot-repair 2017-03-19__10h26 ===================
boot-repair version : 4ppa40
boot-sav version : 4ppa40
glade2script version : 3.2.3~ppa1
boot-sav-extra version : 4ppa40
boot-repair is executed in live-session (Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS, xenial, Ubuntu, x86_64)
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
BOOT_IMAGE=/casper/vmlinuz.efi file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper quiet splash ---
ls: cannot access '/home/usr/.config': No such file or directory

=================== os-prober:


=================== blkid:
/dev/sda1: LABEL="UBUNTU 16_0" UUID="F083-24B4" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="0020a6c3-01"
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/sdb5: UUID="4494e0b5-38c4-4e44-9f26-e376dcd85f76" TYPE="swap"


=================== efibootmgr -v
BootCurrent: 0000
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0000,2001,2002,2003
Boot0000* Linux HD(1,MBR,0x4294967235,0x800,0xf17800)/File(EFIBootgrubx64.efi)RC
Boot0001* Unknown Device:   HD(1,GPT,3da76952-84b7-4a16-99dd-e7db8dc5565d,0x800,0x100000)/File(EFIubuntugrubx64.efi)RC
Boot2001* EFI USB Device    RC
Boot2002* EFI DVD/CDROM RC
Boot2003* EFI Network   RC

=================== UEFI/Legacy mode:
BIOS is EFI-compatible, and is setup in EFI-mode for this live-session.
SecureBoot disabled. (maybe sec-boot, Please report this message to boot.repair@gmail.com)


=================== PARTITIONS & DISKS:



=================== parted -l:

Model: USB Flash DISK (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 8103MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
1      1049kB  8103MB  8102MB  primary  fat32        boot, lba


Model: ATA TOSHIBA MQ01ABD1 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags:

Number  Start  End  Size  File system  Name  Flags

=================== parted -lm:

BYT;
/dev/sda:8103MB:scsi:512:512:msdos:USB Flash DISK:;
1:1049kB:8103MB:8102MB:fat32::boot, lba;

BYT;
/dev/sdb:1000GB:scsi:512:4096:gpt:ATA TOSHIBA MQ01ABD1:;

=================== lsblk:
KNAME TYPE FSTYPE     SIZE LABEL
sdb   disk          931.5G
sdb5  part swap       3.8G
sr0   rom            1024M
loop0 loop squashfs   1.4G
sda   disk            7.6G
sda1  part vfat       7.6G UBUNTU 16_0

KNAME ROTA RO RM STATE   MOUNTPOINT
sdb      1  0  0 running
sdb5     1  0  0         [SWAP]
sr0      1  0  1 running
loop0    1  1  0         /rofs
sda      1  0  1 running
sda1     1  0  1         /cdrom


=================== mount:
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,relatime,size=1917616k,nr_inodes=479404,mode=755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=386640k,mode=755)
/dev/sda1 on /cdrom type vfat (ro,noatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)
/dev/loop0 on /rofs type squashfs (ro,noatime)
aufs on / type aufs (rw,noatime,si=fcadc2d665ad899f)
securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
tmpfs on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k)
tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,release_agent=/lib/systemd/systemd-cgroups-agent,name=systemd)
pstore on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
efivarfs on /sys/firmware/efi/efivars type efivarfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,hugetlb)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/pids type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,pids)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_cls,net_prio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpu,cpuacct)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/devices type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/memory type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,memory)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,perf_event)
systemd-1 on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=26,pgrp=1,timeout=0,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct,pipe_ino=10556)
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,relatime)
hugetlbfs on /dev/hugepages type hugetlbfs (rw,relatime)
mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,relatime)
tracefs on /sys/kernel/debug/tracing type tracefs (rw,relatime)
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw,relatime)
tmpfs on /tmp type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime)
tmpfs on /run/user/999 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=386640k,mode=700,uid=999,gid=999)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/999/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=999,group_id=999)


=================== ls:
/sys/block/sda (filtered):  alignment_offset badblocks bdi capability dev device discard_alignment events events_async events_poll_msecs ext_range holders inflight integrity power queue range removable ro sda1 size slaves stat subsystem trace uevent
/sys/block/sdb (filtered):  alignment_offset badblocks bdi capability dev device discard_alignment events events_async events_poll_msecs ext_range holders inflight integrity power queue range removable ro sdb5 size slaves stat subsystem trace uevent
/sys/block/sr0 (filtered):  alignment_offset badblocks bdi capability dev device discard_alignment events events_async events_poll_msecs ext_range holders inflight integrity power queue range removable ro size slaves stat subsystem trace uevent
/dev (filtered):  autofs block bsg btrfs-control bus cdrom cdrw char console core cpu cpu_dma_latency cuse disk dri drm_dp_aux0 drm_dp_aux1 dvd dvdrw ecryptfs fb0 fd full fuse gpiochip0 hidraw0 hpet hugepages hwrng i2c-0 i2c-1 i2c-10 i2c-11 i2c-12 i2c-2 i2c-3 i2c-4 i2c-5 i2c-6 i2c-7 i2c-8 i2c-9 initctl input kmsg kvm lightnvm log mapper mcelog media0 mei0 mem memory_bandwidth mqueue net network_latency network_throughput null port ppp psaux ptmx pts random rfkill rtc rtc0 sda sda1 sdb sdb5 sg0 sg1 sg2 shm snapshot snd sr0 stderr stdin stdout tpm0 uhid uinput urandom userio v4l vfio vga_arbiter vhci vhost-net video0 zero
ls /dev/mapper:  control

=================== df -Th:

Filesystem     Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev           devtmpfs  1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs          tmpfs     378M  6.2M  372M   2% /run
/dev/sda1      vfat      7.6G  1.5G  6.1G  20% /cdrom
/dev/loop0     squashfs  1.4G  1.4G     0 100% /rofs
aufs           aufs      1.9G   83M  1.8G   5% /
tmpfs          tmpfs     1.9G   57M  1.8G   3% /dev/shm
tmpfs          tmpfs     5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs          tmpfs     1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs          tmpfs     1.9G  704K  1.9G   1% /tmp
tmpfs          tmpfs     378M   88K  378M   1% /run/user/999

=================== fdisk -l:
Disk /dev/ram0: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram1: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram2: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram3: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram4: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram5: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram6: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram7: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram8: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram9: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram10: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram11: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram12: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram13: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram14: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram15: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/loop0: 1.4 GiB, 1497772032 bytes, 2925336 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 7.6 GiB, 8103395328 bytes, 15826944 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x0020a6c3

Device     Boot Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *     2048 15826943 15824896  7.6G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)


Disk /dev/sdb: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 0B524243-FBFC-4881-A5CA-9E4B87E09874


Error: no partitions
Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.


=================== Suggested repair
The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility would not act on the MBR.
Additional repair would be performed:  repair-filesystems


=================== User settings
The settings chosen by the user will not act on the boot.
```

Comment: I have the same problem with the Aspire ES1-732-C18H. Can't find a solution. When installing grub2 (during ubuntu normal installation  or manually from the terminal on the "Try ubuntu mode" the laptop totaly freeze.

Answer (score 0):

You wiped out your /dev/sdb 1TB disk drive with the dd command. dd is also referred to as "disk destroyer", because used incorrectly, it'll do just that.

Time to reinstall Ubuntu and/or Windows from scratch.

Comment: I already did that, and I don't think it has anything to do with that.. in the end I discarded the acer and took out the hard drive (used it in my old HP laptop and it worked fine).